# How can I Modify List items in View (add/remove list items in view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that shows a list of line items based on a PO they searched, fetched from a document.  Once the view is loaded with the line items at the bottom, I have a "x" button next to the entry but not understanding how to perform action on the view items without reloading the page.

Essentially, when the user is done "removing" the line items, I want them to submit and then the form will be put back together but just with the lines left on the view.

(Note:  Using Filehelpers to parse a spacially delimited file, which is why there is so much extra run around and stream and strings. Also note;  New to this!)

Class -

```
namespace WebDocumentEditor
{
    public class LineItemListInfo
    {
        public string asiLineNumber { get; set; }
        public string itemSKU { get; set; }
        public string itemQTY { get; set; }
        public string itemUOM { get; set; }
        public string itemPrice { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller building list:

```
public ActionResult SearchForPODocument(string POinput)
        {
            string contents = string.Empty;
            if (POinput == "" | POinput == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");               
            }
            LoadConfigValues();
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(exportsArchive))
            {
                using (var stream = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    contents = stream.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                    if (contents.Contains(POinput))
                    {

                        SendPOfor850Trim(contents, POinput);
                        ViewBag.DocumentWithPO = documentWithPO;
                        SendFoundPOForASIHDRParse(documentWithPO);
                        SendFoundPOForASISTAParse(documentWithPO);
                        SendFoundPOForASILINParse(documentWithPO);
                        break;                    
                    }
                }
            }
            ViewBag.PoNotFound = "PO Not Found";
            return View();

        }


//Helper Method to break up info from ASISLIN Line
    public void SendFoundPOForASILINParse(string documentWithPO)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ParseASILIN>();
        var result = engine.ReadString(documentWithPO);


        foreach (ParseASILIN parse in result)
        {
            if (parse.lineID.Contains("ASILIN"))
            {
                //action on ASILIN line found
                SetupLineItemInfo(parse.asiLineNumber, parse.itemSKU, parse.itemQTY, parse.itemUOM, parse.itemPrice);
            }
            ViewBag.LineItemList = lineItemList;
        }
    }


    //This moves the parsed info into the LineItemLiftInfo class properties to be appended as a whole line
    public void SetupLineItemInfo(string asiLineNumber, string itemSKU, string itemQTY, string itemUOM, string itemPrice)
    {
        LineItemListInfo fullLineItemCombined = new LineItemListInfo();
        fullLineItemCombined.asiLineNumber = asiLineNumber;
        fullLineItemCombined.itemSKU = itemSKU;
        fullLineItemCombined.itemQTY = itemQTY;
        fullLineItemCombined.itemUOM = itemUOM;
        fullLineItemCombined.itemPrice = itemPrice;

        lineItemList.Add(fullLineItemCombined);
    }
```

View:

## **ASILIN:**

```
<ul id="lineItems" class="list-unstyled">

    <li>
        ASILineNumber | Item Price | Item Quantity | Item SKU | Item Unit Of Measurement
    </li>
    @foreach (var item in (List<LineItemListInfo>)ViewBag.LineItemList)
        {
        <li>
            <button type="button" id="removeLine"class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>

            @item.asiLineNumber | @item.itemPrice | @item.itemQTY | @item.itemSKU | @item.itemUOM
        </li>

    }

</ul>
```

Comment: can u do it with ajax?  u can expose a public method (ie Remove) that accepts Http.Delete verb.  after you r done, u can remove those line with javascripot ( .success()).  absolutely no need to do another post request

Comment: Look at this link, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786085/ASP-NET-MVC-List-Editor-with-Bootstrap-Modals

Comment: achan - that is the missing link I needed brought to my attention:  make and use my own javascript/jquery actions on the list within the view and just call the script on button action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow mark the items for deletion client-side and then post that status back to the server. Utilizing view models, you can add an additional property, such as a bool `Delete`. Then, server-side you can filter items with that bool marked as true, and remove them from the collection.

If you don't want to use view models, then you can have each click of the "x" to delete send an AJAX request to some server-side endpoint that will then actually delete the entity. In your AJAX, you'd simply post something like the primary key, and then use that to lookup the item from the database before deleting it.

Comment: Since I'm using MVC5, it's hard finding relevant examples for implementing scripts, so that's the missing piece.  I need to configure (Angular, jquery, java, ajax, anything really) and implement the script using :  @section scripts
{
    <script src=""></script>
}

Comment: For the sake of moving forward, I am just going to use @section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // your script goes here
    </script>
}

Comment: Part of what confuses people is that MVC is largely unopinionated about how you do anything. It's common to use a section to implement scripts in your view, simply because it allows you to dump that before the closing body tag in your template. Otherwise, there's no magic to using a section. If you didn't want or need that specific placement, then you could just open a script tag anywhere in your view. Also, you can reference external scripts in your section declaration, so using a section doesn't mean your actual script body needs to be there.

Comment: That seems to be the only real issue I'm running into with MVC; the learning curve.  Not having a great grasp of the 4 different languages and syntaxs I'm using (let alone the 10+ you COULD use) in the same structure makes it hard; especially when there is an assumption that you know the rules for each language.  Incredibly expandable and easy to manipulate, I just need to break ground on 'where' everything goes in context of me, since I have that freedom with MVC.

Comment: It's best to start small. People try to jump in a build a completely dynamic JavaScript-dependent web application from scratch with no base knowledge. Start with the bare minimum to achieve what you want, instead, and the refine and expand from there. Personally, I'd avoid JS completely until you've got something working well without it. Then progressively enhance with JS to make the UI easier and more efficient. Take each piece one at a time, and you'll not only have a better understanding of how each thing works, but you'll end up building a more robust app in the process.